# how to execute a set of php files from a directory

Tags: php, wordpress, joomla

The issue is like this.......

I have Joomla and WordPress installed on one site and I have a set of PHP files, lets say....

file1.php
file2.php
file3.php 
and so on....

which are saved in a particular folder lets sat FOLDER-1. These files have some scripts which get data from Joomla or WordPress.

I want to call a refresh option in my template parameters where we ask the user if he wants to refresh the files, If he chooses yes then I want that all PHP files in this **FOLDER-1** must run once and perform their respective PHP actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (glob("*.php") as $filename) {
    include($filename);
}
```

Adjust `glob` argument to use whatever directory you want to search for .php files in.

Comment: And I wrap the whole thing in a if statement related to my user option of refresh? Just one more thing is it not that this INCLUDE statement need some page refresh for getting executed? Will all these files run upon satisfying the wrapped IF statement?

Comment: This is a loop. The body of the loop will run once per matched file name. The effect of `include` is the same as pasting the contents of the included file at that point, so the PHP in each matched file will be executed as if it appeared there. No page refresh occurs.

Comment: Oh ok yes I realized that. It worked as expected. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the help buddy.